# Infiinite nested collections in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a very simple Backbone example:

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend();

var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: myModel,


});

var c = new collection([
    {first_name: 'a', 
     last_name:'b'
    },
    {first_name:'c', 
     last_name:'d'
    }
    ]);

console.log('c is');
console.log(c);
```

You can see jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/73qn9fjg/1/).

When you view this in Chrome developer tools, you can see there is a collection attribute on each Backbone model, which you can expand and go into again, infintely. See the image:

[image]

What is this? Why does it appear like that?

Comment: Each model holds a reference to the collection that it's in; Each collection holds the references to the model it holds - this is the loop you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside every model there is a collection object stored if it is part of a collection. What is happening here is you are viewing collection in console and inside it there are two models. Each model has collection object stored in it (which is the same collection which you are viewing). So, it seems like sort of recursion when viewing in console

This is currently not documented in backbone js. See https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/1161 for more info.